# How to capture bootstrap dropdown values in react without third-party libraries?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5.1 without third-party libaries like react-bootstrap or ... in my React App.
I am able to see the dropdown button is working properly on my react app but I cannot capture the values on selecting different options of drop down. I tried to replace the `<a>` tags with `<option value='...'>` but wasn't successful . Any idea ?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` tag doesn't support `value` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Similarly, you can't have `option` tag without a `select`/`datalist`/`optgroup` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

If you need some type of value associated with the tags anyway, use something like: `data-value={your_value}`. And then work with the dataset of the element clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code

```
export default function App() {
  const onChangeClick = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };
  return (
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a
        class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        href="#"
        role="button"
        id="dropdownMenuLink"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        Dropdown link
      </a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item"
            href="#"
            onClick={() => onChangeClick("action")}
          >
            Action
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item"
            href="#"
            onClick={() => onChangeClick("another action")}
          >
            Another action
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            class="dropdown-item"
            href="#"
            onClick={() => onChangeClick("else action")}
          >
            Something else here
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think that rendering multiple onClick for each elemnt will decrease the optimization level of the app and is not the proper way.